# Is stream().takeWhile thread safe on LinkedBlockingQueue

Tags: java, thread-safety, linkedblockingqueue

can anyone explain me if in java

```
//Thread 1
BlockingQueue<String> queue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();
queue.put("232323232");
.....
//Thread 2
Stream<String> result = queue.stream().takeWhile(predicate);
```

is thread safe? ... if one thread is puts in queue and another is reading with stream takeWhile the queue data?

Comment: I don't think so, cuz .stream is method of Collection interface it is the same with foreach loop. usage of ConcurrentLinkedQueue must be safe